# What's the meaning of the -azo suffix?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sufijos

1. What's the meaning of the (noun)-**azo**?
2. How the nouns are transformed into their -azo noun?
3. In which cases should be used?

Examples:

- zapatazo
- golpazo

Comment: Regarding *golpazo*, I think it is more common in Spain to say *golpetazo*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *-azo/za* suffix has four different functions:

- As an augmentative: *perrazo*, *manaza* (a big dog, a big hand).
- As a pejorative: *aceitazo* (dense and turbid oil).
- It can express a hit given with the object represented by the word to which it is appended:  *martillazo* (a hit given with a hammer), *almohadazo* (a hit given with a pillow).
- Sometimes, it can also express a hit given the object represented by the word to which it is appended: *espaldarazo* (a hit given in the back); it's worth mentioning that *espaldarzo* not only stands for the hit given in the back, but also for a sign of recognition and aprovement (see example below).

Here are some example sentences:

> *Rompió el bastón con sus manazas morenas* (She/he broke the stick with his big brown hands).
>
> *Mi esposa no quiere ese aceitazo ni regalado* (My wife wouldn't accept that turbid oil even if it was free).
>
> *Todos recordamos el zapatazo propinado al presidente iraní Mahmud Ahmadineyad* (we all remember the hit given with a shoe to Iran's President Mahmud Ahmadineyad).
>
> *Monti recibe espaldarazo del Parlamento italiano* (Monti receives support from the Italian Parliament).

In your concrete examples, *zapatazo* y *golpazo*, the particle *-azo* acts as augmentative.

Some of the rules governing the addition of the *-azo/za* suffix are:

- Words ending in a non-tonic vowel, loose the vowel:

  > porra, porrazo.
  >
  > golpe, golpazo.
  >
  > mano, manaza.
- Words ending in a consonant, simply add the suffix:

  > sol, solazo.
  >
  > perol, perolazo